# New segmentation fault with previously working C code

Tags: c, linux, file-io, segmentation-fault

this code is meant to take a list of names in a text file, and convert to email form

so Kate Jones becomes kate.jones@yahoo.com
this code worked fine on linux mint 12, but now the exact same code is giving a segfault on arch linux.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  FILE *fp;
  fp = fopen("original.txt", "r+");
  if (fp == NULL )
  {
    printf("error opening file 1");
    return (1);
  }

  char line[100];
  char mod[30] = "@yahoo,com\n";
  while (fgets(line, 100, fp) != NULL )
  {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    {
      if (line[i] == ' ')
      {
        line[i] = '.';
      }
      if (line[i] == '\n')
      {
        line[i] = '\0';
      }

    }

    strcat(line, mod);

    FILE *fp2;
    fp2 = fopen("final.txt", "a");

    if (fp == NULL )
    {
      printf("error opening file 2");
      return (1);
    }

    if (fp2 != NULL )
    {
      fputs(line, fp2);
      fclose(fp2);
    }

  }

  fclose(fp);

  return 0;
}
```

Arch Linux is a fairly fresh install, could it be that there is something else I didn't install that C will need?

Comment: Single step using a debugger. Which row gives the seg fault?

Comment: Where is the fault? Did you try a debugger? Also, you append a string (with a comma in it which looks fishy in a domain name) even though the input string (in `line`) might be close to the buffer limit of 100 chars, that's bad. Further, don't open and close the output for every line you've processed, that's going to be super slow.

Comment: Use `gdb` to debug your code, and find out exact statement which is causing Seg Fault

Comment: After opening "final.txt" you check for `fp == NULL` instead of `fp2`. But as you check again before writing, that shouldn't cause the seg fault

Comment: The `strcat()` is suspect.

Comment: I think the only place where that can crash is with strcat(). Show us your input file.

Comment: For the sake of completion typo @yahoo.com (Should be a . not ,)

Answer (score 9):

I think the problem would be when your **original string plus mod exceeds 100** characters.

When you call **strcat**, it simply copies the string from the second appended to the first, assuming there is enough room in the first string which clearly doesn't seem to be the case here.

Just increase the size of line i.e. it could be

```
char line[130]; // 130 might be more than what is required since mod is shorter
```

Also it is much better to use [strncat](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strncat.3.html)

where you can limit maximum number of elements copied to dst, otherwise, strcat can *still go beyond size without complaining* if given large enough strings.

*Though a word of caution with strncat is that it does not terminate strings with null i.e. \0 on its own, specially when they are shorter than the given n. So its documentation should be thoroughly read before actual use.*

**Update: Platform specific note**

Thought of adding, it is by sheer coincidence that it *didn't seg fault* on mint and crashed on arch. In practice it is invoking *undefined behavior* and should crash sooner or latter. There is nothing platform specific here.

Comment: Your `char line[130]` suggestion is great and +1 for that.

But, suggestion of `char *strncat(char *dest, const char *src, size_t n);` doesn't help you in all the cases. 
As for `strcat()` buffer size of the `dest` must be atleast `strlen(dest) +strlen(src) +1`. For`strncat()` the buffer size of the `dest` must be atleast `strlen(dest) + n + 1`, else again you will run into stack buffer overflow.

Comment: Agreed, i wasn't implying that either. Point was that if you are including a size parameter, you are definitely going to check if the total size of destination fits that in and would stick to it. This would work even when the source string doesn't have a terminating null. It won't carry more than total n chars. So if the given string is large enough, strncpy would still stick to the size passed (assuming the size never goes beyond total of destination).

Answer (score 2):

Firstly your code isn't producing segmentation fault. Instead it will bring up **"Stack Smashing"** and throws below libc_message in the output console.

```
*** stack smashing detected ***: _executable-name-with-path_ terminated.
```

Stack buffer overflow bugs are caused when a program writes more data to a buffer located on the stack than there was actually allocated for that buffer.

Stack Smashing Protector (SSP) is a GCC extension for protecting applications from such stack-smashing attacks.

And, as said in other answers, your problem gets resolved with incrementing (`strcat()` function's first argument). from

```
char line[100]
```

to

```
char line[130]; // size of line must be atleast `strlen(line) + strlen(mod) + 1`. Though 130 is not perfect, it is safer
```

---

Lets see where the issue exactly hits in your code:

For that I am bringing up disassembly code of your main.

```
(gdb) disas main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x0804857c <+0>: push   %ebp
   0x0804857d <+1>: mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x0804857f <+3>: and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
   0x08048582 <+6>: sub    $0xb0,%esp
   0x08048588 <+12>: mov    %gs:0x14,%eax
   0x0804858e <+18>: mov    %eax,0xac(%esp)

   .....  //Leaving out Code after 0x0804858e till 0x08048671

   0x08048671 <+245>:   call   0x8048430 <strcat@plt>
   0x08048676 <+250>:   movl   $0x80487d5,0x4(%esp)

   .... //Leaving out Code after 0x08048676 till 0x08048704

   0x08048704 <+392>:   mov    0xac(%esp),%edx
   0x0804870b <+399>:   xor    %gs:0x14,%edx
   0x08048712 <+406>:   je     0x8048719 <main+413>
   0x08048714 <+408>:   call   0x8048420 <__stack_chk_fail@plt>
   0x08048719 <+413>:   leave
   0x0804871a <+414>:   ret
```

Following the usual assembly language prologue,

Instruction at `0x08048582` : stack grows by b0(176 in decimal) bytes for allowing storage stack contents for the main function.

%gs:0x14 provides the random canary value used for stack protection.

Instruction at `0x08048588` : Stores above mentioned value into the eax register.

Instruction at `0x0804858e` : `eax` content(canary value) is pushed to stack at $esp with offset 172

Keep a breakpoint(1) at `0x0804858e`.

```
(gdb) break *0x0804858e
Breakpoint 1 at 0x804858e: file program_name.c, line 6.
```

Run the program:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /path-to-executable/executable-name 

Breakpoint 1, 0x0804858e in main () at program_name.c:6
6   {
```

Once program pauses at the breakpoint(1), Retreive the random canary value by printing the contents of  register 'eax'

```
(gdb) i r eax
eax            0xa3d24300   -1546501376
```

Keep a breakpoint(2) at `0x08048671` : Exactly before call `strcat()`.

```
(gdb) break *0x08048671
Breakpoint 2 at 0x8048671: file program_name.c, line 33.
```

Continue the program execution to reach the breakpoint (2)

```
(gdb) continue
Continuing.

Breakpoint 2, 0x08048671 in main () at program_name.c:33
```

print out the second top stack content where we stored the random canary value by executing following command in gdb, to ensure it is the same before `strcat()` is called.

```
(gdb) p *(int*)($esp + 172)
$1 = -1546501376
```

Keep a breakpoint (3) at `0x08048676` : Immediately after returning from call `strcat()`

```
(gdb) break *0x08048676
Breakpoint 3 at 0x8048676: file program_name.c, line 36.
```

Continue the program execution to reach the breakpoint (3)

```
(gdb) continue
Continuing.

Breakpoint 3, main () at program_name.c:36
```

print out the second top stack content where we stored the random canary value by executing following command in gdb, to ensure it is not corrupted by calling `strcat()`

```
(gdb) p *(int*)($esp + 172)
$2 = 1869111673
```

But it is corrupted by calling `strcat()`. You can see `$1` and `$2` are not same. 
Lets see what happens because of corrupting the random canary value.

Instruction at `0x08048704` : Pulls the corrupted random canary value and stores in 'edx` register

Instruction at `0x0804870b` : xor the actual random canary value and the contents of 'edx' register

Instruction at `0x08048712` : If they are same, jumps directly to end of main and returns safely. In our case random canary value is corrupted and 'edx' register contents is not the same as the actual random canary value. Hence Jump condition fails and __stack_chk_fail is called which throws libc_message mentioned in the top of the answer and aborts the application.

Useful Links:

[IBM SSP Page](http://www.research.ibm.com/trl/projects/security/ssp/)

[Interesting Read on SSP](http://www.hackitoergosum.org/2010/HES2010-prascagneres-Stack-Smashing-Protector-in-FreeBSD.pdf) - caution pdf.

Comment: Very detailed one and interesting (though cumbersome) read. +1

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't tell us where it faults I'll just point out some suspect lines:

```
for(i=0; i<100; ++i)
```

What if a line is less than 100 chars? This will read uninitialized memory - its not a good idea to do this.

```
strcat(line, mod);
```

What if a line is 90 in length and then you're adding 30 more chars? Thats 20 out of bounds..

You need to calculate the length and dynamically allocate your strings with malloc, and ensure you don't read or write out of bounds, and that your strings are always NULL terminated. Or you could use C++/std::string to make things easier if it doesn't *have* to be C.

Comment: The for loop is not dangerous. The line may be less than 100 chars, but he allocated 100 chars, he's free to read them all, even if they contain garbage. It's not invalid memory access, it's just reading something uninitialized. strcat(), on the other hand, is suspicious.

Comment: You're right.. I forgot its a statically sized buffer :) I'll update my answer

Comment: Use dynamic allocation to increase memory footprint and reduce performance? Nasty. It's natural limitation, if name is 100Mb large - surely noone wants this email, it just need to be discarded/error reported/etc.

Comment: How would it increase memory footprint? If no strings are larger than 10 bytes it would reduce the memory footprint. If the data is user supplied then you can't assume anything about its size.

Comment: @paulm dynamic allocation costs more memory then you've requested because it needs to keep internal track somewhere. Performance too - it takes quite sophisticated algorithms to find free blocks, split them, etc.. Stack, on the contrary, always here, costs no additional CPU instructions to allocate (one instruction per function, regardless), doesn't require freeing and have no overhead other then specified size. Moreover, there are VLA and alloca, if size could vary too significantly. And yes, you can assume anything if you know what you're reading - user with megabyte-name could go to hell.

Comment: Just like how people with very long names can't have them fit on their drivers license? Likely because there is a char buf[128] somewhere!

Comment: @paulm you mean, if you have million-symbols-long name, you still should have it in your passport? Which in result would weight, say, 2048kg? Please be sane when choosing a name then. If your program could read that kind of name - it wouldn't change the world anyway.

Comment: million might be overkill, but 100 is too short for some peoples names

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking for `\n` only, for the end of line, add the check for `\r` character also.

`if(line[i] == '\n' || line[i] == '\r')`

Also, before using `strcat` ensure that `line` has has enough room for `mod`. You can do this by checking if `(i < /* Some value far less than 100 */)`, if `i == 100` then that means it never encountered a `\n` character hence `\0` was not added to `line`, hence Invalid memory Access occurs inside `strcat()` and therefore **Seg Fault**.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it.  I simply increased the size of my line string.

Comment: except it only works when run in mono, the exact same code gives a segfault in geany, how could this be?

Comment: What?... Mono is runtime for C# and others, geany is text editor. What the hell are you talking about? Hot're you executing your C code in text editor? Does it have builtin Ch or whatever?